# devise sign in with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I know I'm asking a common question, however I hope I have a different spin on it.

I've walked into a prebuilt app that doesn't have a user table, instead it has 2 user type tables - `students and contributors`. There are separate Devise sign in pages associated with both. I need to combine the sign in's to a single page.

Models:

```
class Contributor < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :async, :confirmable


class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :async, :confirmable
```

Routes:

```
 devise_for :contributors, controllers: {registrations: 'contributors/registrations', confirmations: 'contributors/confirmations'}
 devise_for :students, controllers: {registrations: 'students/registrations', confirmations: 'students/confirmations'}
```

The Views are exactly the same, just 2 separate files:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} ) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :email, :autofocus => true %>

  <%= f.input :password %>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <%= f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: false, inline_label: 'Remember me?' %>
  <% end -%>

  <div class="controls">
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign in', :class => 'btn-primary submit' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What I was wondering is if I could get the view resource to check back against both the contributor and student class, instead of going through separate files.

Comment: Have you considered `ActiveRecord` polymorphic association? I mean you have a `User` class with descendants `Contributor` and `Student`. Then you only authenticate `User` but since user has a polymorphic association to its descendants, you still have context of `Contributor` and `Student`. Do you get the idea?

Comment: @blelump, not exactly. I don't have a user table set up. only the contributor and student tables.